# How to get the live location of mouse in java swing?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, mouselistener

I am trying to create a simple tic-tac-toe game and I want to display highlight on the square where the mouse is located. I draw the game on `java.awt.Canvas` and currently, I've tried these methods that failed:

- I've tried to add a `MouseAdapter` to my Canvas and override its `mouseEnter` method but it worked just on the time that cursor entered the Canvas(As it is supposed to).
- Then I added 9 `JPanel`s(one for each square) and added a `MouseAdapter` to each. But it didn't work, too. I searched about the reason and I found that I should `requestFocus()` to enable listeners.

By the way, here is my code:

Class for overriding `MouseAdaper`'s methods:

```
public class MouseInput extends MouseAdapter {

    private final Game game;
    private final int i;
    private final int j;

    public MouseInput(Game game, JPanel panel){
        this.game = game;
        i = panel.getY() / 64;
        j = panel.getX() / 64;
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        game.mouseEntered(i, j);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        game.mouseExited(i, j);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
        game.mouseClicked(i, j);
    }
}
```

`JPanel`s in game and adding `MouseListener` to them:

```
public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable {
    private boolean isRunning = false;
    private Thread thread;
    private final JPanel[][] panels = new JPanel[3][3];

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Game game = new Game();
        game.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(192, 192));

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(game);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        game.start();
    }

    private void start(){
        if(isRunning){
            return;
        }

        isRunning = true;
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }

    private void stop(){
        if(!isRunning){
            return;
        }

        isRunning = false;
        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {}
        System.exit(0);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
                JPanel p  = new JPanel();
                p.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(64, 64));
                p.setLocation(j * 64, i * 64);
                p.addMouseListener(new MouseInput(this, p));
                panels[i][j] = p;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swing is NOT thread safe and is SINGLE threaded.  You should not be updating the UI or updating something UI relies on from outside the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.

In your case, the panels aren't actually attached to anything (ie added to a container) and therefore can not respond to any events.

You should also take the time to learn some of the layout management basics.

[image: Mouse Moving]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();

                JPanel board = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 3));
                for (int index = 0; index < 9; index++) {
                    board.add(new GridPane());
                }

                frame.add(board);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class GridPane extends JPanel {

        private MouseListener mouseHandler;

        public GridPane() {
            setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(50, 50);
        }

        @Override
        public void addNotify() {
            super.addNotify(); 

            if (mouseHandler != null) {
                removeMouseListener(mouseHandler);
            }

            mouseHandler = new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                    setBackground(Color.RED);
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                    setBackground(null);
                }
            };

            addMouseListener(mouseHandler);
        }

        @Override
        public void removeNotify() {
            super.removeNotify();
            if (mouseHandler != null) {
                removeMouseListener(mouseHandler);
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Rather than trying to have a single listener trying to update the game model.  Pass the game reference to each panel and have it do that job.  This way you could pass a "identifier" to each cell which could be passed back to the game so it can make some decisions it needs to.